Compute $\mathbb{E}\left\{ X^\ast X^H \right\}$ where $X$ is complex Gaussian
Given $X \sim \mathcal{CN}\left( \mathbf{0}, \Sigma \right) \in \mathbb{C}^{d}$ is a $d$-dimension complex Gaussian random vector with covariance matrix $\Sigma$.
Of note, $\Sigma$ is positive semi-definite.
My goal is to find:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left\{ X^\ast X^H \right\}
$$
where $X^\ast = (X^H)^T$ is the element-wise complex conjugate of $X$.
First, I apply the Cholesky decomposition $\Sigma = \mathbf{L} \mathbf{L}^T$ so that
$$
X \sim \mathbf{L}^T Y,\quad Y \sim \mathcal{CN}\left( \mathbf{0}, \mathbf{I} \right).
$$
With the fact that $(\mathbf{L}^T)^H = \mathbf{L}$ since $\Sigma$ is positive semi-definite, making $\mathbf{L}$ real, I obtain:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left\{ X^\ast X^H \right\} = \mathbf{L}^T \mathbb{E}\left\{ Y^\ast Y^H \right\} \mathbf{L}
$$
Since $\mathbb{E}\left\{ Y^\ast Y^H \right\} = \mathbf{0}$, I obtain $\mathbb{E}\left\{ X^\ast X^H \right\} = \mathbf{0}$.
Is this true? And if not, how should I find $\mathbb{E}\left\{ X^\ast X^H \right\}$ or $\mathbb{E}\left\{ Y^\ast Y^H \right\}$?

Your derivation is mostly correct, but with two caveats:

$X$ must also be circularly symmetric. You haven't explicitly stated it as such, but it is implied to some degree since you've only used the mean and covariance to describe the distribution. It's better to explicitly state this somewhere when defining $X$.
Since you're dealing in general with a complex-valued covariance matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ with the complex normal distribution, the Cholesky decomposition should properly be defined as $\mathbf{\Sigma} = \mathbf{LL}^H$ rather than $\mathbf{LL}^T$. Only the diagonal elements of $\mathbf{L}$ will be real; the off-diagonal elements may still be complex.

More generally, you can also get the same result by specifying that $\mathbf{\Sigma} = \mathbf{RR}^H$, where $\mathbf{R} = \mathbf{\Sigma}^{1/2}$ is the matrix square root of $\mathbf{\Sigma}$. Since $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is positive semi-definite, you will get $\mathbf{R} = \mathbf{R}^H$. Note that $\mathbf{R}$ here is not necessarily unique. You can multiply $\mathbf{R}$ by any $d{\times}d$ unitary matrix $\mathbf{U}$ to get $\tilde{\mathbf{R}} = \mathbf{RU}$, and $\tilde{\mathbf{R}}$ will still be a valid matrix square root of $\mathbf{\Sigma}$. The Cholesky decomposition, singular value decomposition, and QR (or LQ) decomposition are all ways you can obtain a value for $\mathbf{R}$.
Even more simply, though, is just the fact that $\mathbb{E}\{X^* X^H\} = (\mathbb{E}\{XX^T\})^H$. If $X$ is circularly symmetric with zero mean, then by definition, $\mathbb{E}\{XX^T\} = \mathbf{0}$ (with dimensions $d{\times}d$). Thus, $\mathbb{E}\{X^* X^H\} = \mathbf{0}^H = \mathbf{0}$. On the other hand, if $X$ is not circularly symmetric, then the complex normal distribution must be specified with a third parameter, e.g., $X \sim \mathcal{CN}(\mathbf{\mu},\mathbf{\Sigma},\mathbf{C})$ (see for instance here). $\mathbf{C}$ is the pseudo-covariance or relation matrix, defined as $\mathbf{C} = \mathbb{E}\{(X-\mathbf{\mu})(X-\mathbf{\mu})^T\} = \mathbb{E}\{XX^T\} - \mathbf{\mu\mu}^T$. We therefore end up with:
$$\mathbb{E}\{X^* X^H\} = (\mathbb{E}\{XX^T\})^H = \mathbf{C}^H + (\mathbf{\mu\mu}^T)^H = \mathbf{C}^H + \mathbf{\mu}^*\mathbf{\mu}^H$$

Thank you so much for such a detailed answer. After searching a lot, I found out about the pseudo-covariance or relation matrix thing. My field is wireless communication and most applications that I study nowadays do not mention about pseudo-covariance matrices as they are assumed to be zero.

Yes, indeed. Circularly symmetric is such a common assumption for complex Gaussian vectors that many people don't know at first that it can be something else. In the context of wireless communications, it doesn't make much sense in most cases for the in-phase and quadrature parts of the wireless channel to follow different distributions. Thus, being circularly symmetric just tends to not even be mentioned and is implicitly assumed that way.
